# Cannot set the lastViewedByMeDate parameter for a file on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to set the value of the lastViewedByMeDate parameter for a file on Google drive. Setting request goes fine. When I retrieve the value of the property it is offset (delayed) from the time I set it to.
    Referring to the page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update  I tried this by setting the parameter updateViewedDate to false also. Setting it to false reduces the delay to like 3 seconds but it is still not what I set it to.

Is there something I am not doing right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you experiencing? I tried updating a random file's lastViewedByMeDate with `2016-08-13T07:20:48.424Z`, it works fine and I was the update correctly using the [try it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#try-it) in the update method page.

Comment: Yes seems to be working fine. I am not sure why I was getting a different value when last time I was reading it back.